# State its null In React native using ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Anyone can explain me why I'm getting something like: 'null is not an object (evaluating this.state.sessionState)' even if I'm explicitly declaring the state inside the constructor?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { sessionState: false };
}
render() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
      <View style={mainStyle.head}>
        {this.state.sessionState?Feed:Welcome}
      </View>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you replace `{this.state.sessionState?Feed:Welcome}` with `{this.state.sessionState?'Feed':'Welcome'}` instead?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that's actually generating the bug? My guess is you're evaluating `this.state` in a function that's unbound from the component - so you'll need to bind it in the constructor or use class property declaration syntax

Comment: @cdaiga I don't understand why I need to replace these, Feed and Welcome are variables that return some components.

Comment: @CesarJrRodriguez , do a Ctrl+F or Cmd+F in your file to see every place you are using `this.state.sessionState`. The snippet you provided might not be causing the error

Comment: It is possible that you're accessing that state variable in an unbound function as @GeoffreyAbdallah mentioned. Assuming that function is called `foo()`, within your constructor after `super()`, include this line: `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)`

Comment: Seems that the problem is I'm using Expo. The hot reload doesn't works as expected. I've restarted the app and works correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload your page if you change your sessionState to true or false and then you will get your result..

and if you providing true to your state then it will be definitely  print Feed as per your statement because conditional operator execute  first statement as true and second one as false, so if you provide false to your state and then reload your page you will get 'welcome'

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the most close answer to the problem, I'm figured was a stuff related to Expo Framework. However when I restarted the package in the app everything works as expected.

Comment: its not related to framework, when you use a state you need to reload it,so when you go to that page, the constructor will initialize with state , and you will get proper result , no need to restart package

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thats how React works, however what I could see was that the problem was solved just installing the whole app over again (I mean, Ctrl+C and npm start in console for compiling)

Answer (score 0):

Well, [this](https://snack.expo.io/BJHoD5us-) works as expected

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { sessionState: true };
}
render() {
  return (

      <View >
        <Text> </Text>
        <Text> the message is </Text>
        <Text> {this.state.sessionState?'Feed':'Welcome'}</Text>
      </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: When I set sessionState : true Text stills printing Welcome instead Feed.

Comment: How that comes? maybe something is wrong? just changed the link to modify the `sessionState` to `true` so that Feed was print, check it out :D